# Creating a) list in html

Tags: html, css

I want to create an HTML list like

```
a) first Point
b) second Point
c) third Point
```

but there isn't a option like that in the HTML type-attribute. A solution with CSS would be even better. For me it is important, that the code works in every common browser.

Comment: In html use &lt;ol&gt; 'ordered list' to have letters as placeholders you need to use CSS: **ol{list-style-type:lower-latin;}** for lower case latin list markers.

Answer (score 1):

Lists support numbers and letters through the type attribute. 
 `<ol type="1|a|A|i|I">` for lowercase letters in your list use the lower case a. e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/4jyc978o/

```
<ol type="a">
<li> first point</li>
<li> second point</li>
<li> third point</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: They want a parenthesis after the letter.